# Lion clean install process

Tags: macos, hard-drive, upgrade

I'm fairly new to Macs, so I wanted to check if this was a good way to update my machine. Also I'll comment on my reqs so perhaps there's a better way.

So, I have a MBP 2010 160GB Snow Leopard latest. What I want to do is update to Lion, but, as many have suggested it may be a better idea to do a clean install. Also, I've been wanting to upgrade my HDD to a 320 or 500GB, so I guess this is a good oportunity to do both.

I was thinking in:

1. Purchase and download Lion and make a bootable DVD.
2. Backup all necessary files in TimeMachine.
3. Make the HDD upgrade.
4. Install Lion in new HDD
5. Restore files/settings with TimeMachine.
6. Enjoy!

Does this make sense? What worries me more is step 5... Do you think this is  a good approach or do you have a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: And the old archive and install steps to clean are no longer meaningful for Lion - it's the same running the migration assistant later or just upgrading Lion - the same clean install and migration happens whether you do them in one "action" or do it later as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't complicate things with a DVD. Just set up your new drive using an external USB adaptor (or a full drive enclosure / drive toaster) and [install Lion cleanly](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) there. You can boot to it, migrate over apps or users. It won't get the Recovery HD until you swap the drives, but you can re-run (or re-download) the Lion installer a second time to have it drop the Recovery HD on the now internal Lion drive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent [article at ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2011/07/ask-ars-do-i-have-to-use-the-mac-app-store-to-install-lion.ars) on how to create your own Lion installer USB, and how to use it. It's entitled "Ask Ars: Do I have to use the Mac App Store to reinstall Lion?" by Chris Foresman.